# Error when adding a GitHub link to a Teams page

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

I'm attempting to add a GitHub link to my [Team's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/edit/11).

The GitHub url is https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers

I first tried to enter the link as-is above. I got the following tool tip:

[image]

Then I got an error page when I tried to submit.

I then tried the value `SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers`. This did not give me a popup error, but still an error page when I tried to submit.

Comment: Do note it does the same for twitter, with the difference it does save the twitter url. Also it's only an info message altough doesn't seem to be needed there since most users will probably just copy paste the url.

Comment: Looks like you've uncovered a bug! ;) Geoff has found the issue and is working on it.

Comment: This question is about the *old* Teams feature, which has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this has been deployed.

Comment: As of version "2015.11.9.2958", I can add the full link and submit with no errors, however I still get the blue popup warning (when entering the url)