# Team github URL cannot specify a hierarchical URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

I have already looked at [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309749/error-when-adding-a-github-link-to-a-teams-page), but I am currently trying to add `PlatformLab/RAMCloud`, but the `/` is disallowed, so this is rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're aware of this issue, and we're going to fix it to allow configuring a repository in the Github field (there was a [discussion in chat about it as well](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26779355#26779355)).

*Currently*, you can only use an organization or user.